# Code Effects: Create a custom Action that accepts an expression?

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

Is it possible to create a custom Action on my that accepts an expression like the built in `Set` method does?

EX:

```
    public class EvaluatorClass {
        [Action]
        public void SetSomeThing(Expression myExpression) {
            var result = myExpression();

            --do some other stuff using the value returned from the above expression--
    }
```

Comment: The current 5.x version does not support expressions as params. A variation of this functionality will be implemented in the next major version of the Code Effects business rules engine.